# Uninstall node and npm on android?

Tags: node.js, npm, termux

Believe it or not, its not the same removing node and npm on android as it is on linux. Does anybody know how to uninstall node and npm? Or to reinstall it or even just update it. Im in the dark here...
*I have termux by the way*

Comment: How did you install nodejs?

Answer (score 3):

In termux you can remove node via apt/pkg if you install node with termux package manger. Only two packages provide node in termux. `nodejs, nodejs-lts` remove both if you can't recall what you have installed last time

```
pkg remove nodejs nodejs-lts
```

If you have installed node lite then replace that name.

FYI you can list installed package in termux via `pkg list-installed`